# Unable to load package In R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I've been getting this error since yesterday whenever I try to load tidyverse package:

```
library(tidyverse) 

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’: .onAttach
> failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details: call: NULL
> error: package or namespace load failed for ‘ggplot2’ in get(Info[i,
> 1], envir = env): cannot open file 'C:/Users/My
> PC/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2/colorspace/R/colorspace.rdb': No
> such file or directory



library(tidyverse)
```

expect this package to load but it doesn't

Comment: You need to give us more details.  How did you install R?  How did you install tidyverse and its dependencies, including in particular colorspace and ggplot2, the ones mentioned in the error message?  Which versions were installed?

Comment: I installed the latest R version (4.2.3) and the latest Rstudio.
I installed the tidyverse packages using install.packages("tidyverse")
I loaded the tidyverse package using the library(tidyverse). But I keep getting errors which don't happen before.
I tried to use older versions like 4.2.2, 4.2.1 etc yet nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have really installed the library. If you are on R Studio you can check there among the list of packages installed, if you are on Anaconda you can check the installed R packages from the Anaconda app.

This error is mainly happening because you have not installed the package you are calling or because your installation is not compatible with the installed R version. I got a similar problem one time with Jupyter Notebook, had to reset the R kernel from scratch and install packages one by one, but it worked properly in the end.

Edit: After seeing more information from your post, I can say that your problem is quite similar to the one in this thread https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/97. Go through it and try the fixes listed there.

Comment: I installed the tidyverse package before loading it but keep getting the same error.

Comment: @AbiolaHussein Try the fix in the link I shared, it may help you as the issue they faced was similar to yours.